# Facebook like user search as you type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am creating a messaging system for my web app and need help with searching for users to send messages to. So far I have it so that if you type a persons name (who is on the site) you can send a message to them. I want it to be as you start typing a persons name, a drop down appears with users names that the current user is following. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

I am using the gem mailboxer also wondering if anyone has suggestions for a better messaging gem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery autocomplete,](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and just populate the dropdown contents as all users that the user is following... something like `current_user.followed_users`. It's impossible to give code without seeing how your code works though.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this was enough to help

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to jquery autocomplete is http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/  and github at: https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput. A facebook like tagging to send message to multiple users. A demo app on https://github.com/railscasts/258-token-fields-revised/tree/master/bookstore-tokeninput-after from Ryan Bates from Railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

Good luck.